# Inequality for diagonal element of the inverse of a sum of matrices

Tags: matrices

I have a square matrix of the form:

$$M = X^T X + A$$

where $A$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are positive, and $X$ is a rectangular matrix (assume that matrix dimensions in this equation are consistent). Then, $M$ is positive definite and symmetric. In particular, it is invertible.

Is the following inequality true in general?

$$(M^{-1})_{nn} < \frac{1}{a_{nn}}$$

where $a_{nn}$ denotes the diagonal entries of $A$. I've done some numerical simulations with random matrices and it seems to hold. But I have not been able to prove it in general.

Comment: Let $B=X'X$. Then, $M=B+A$, and $M^{-1} = (B+A)^{-1}$. Intuitively, since $(b+a)^{-1} \le a^{-1}$ for positive scalars, your inequality is a matrix version of this idea. As noted by Mark below, the key idea here is to observe that $M \ge A$, and then conclude that $M^{-1} \le A^{-1}$, from which it follows that $e_n^TM^{-1}e_n=(M^{-1})_{nn} \le 1/a_{nn}$. This question is, however, not really a research question, and I feel it may be more suitable for M.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim as stated is trivially false. Choose $X =$ matrix of zeros. Then $(M^{-1})_{nn} = \frac{1}{a_{nn}}$

However, $(M^{-1})_{nn} \le \frac{1}{a_{nn}}$ is true, because $M - A$ is positive semidefinite. Therefore, $A^{-1} -M^{-1}$ is positive semidefinite (see derivation below), and thus has nonnegative diagonal elements.

Here is a derivation that $M \succeq A$ implies $M^{-1} \preceq A^{-1}$, given of course, as is the case here, that $M^{-1}$ and $A^{-1}$ exist.

By Schur complement on the identity matrix, $I$, in the below, we have that $M \succeq A$ implies
$$\left[\begin{array}{l}I&A^{1/2}\\A^{1/2}&M\end{array}\right] \succeq 0$$.  Now applying Schur complement on $M$, we have $$I - A^{1/2}M^{-1}A^{1/2} \succeq 0$$ Applying a similarity transform with $A^{-1/2}$ to the LHS, which leaves its eigenvalues unchanged, we have $A^{-1} - M^{-1} \succeq 0$

Comment: So if $X^T X$ is positive-definite then the strict equality holds.

Comment: I did not understand the step where you claim that $A^{-1} - M^{-1}$ is positive semi-definite? How do you get to that?

Comment: Although this proves the result, I feel like there should be a more "direct" derivation. I still don't feel like I *see* why it is true.

Comment: For future reference, the Schur complementarity theorem needed is Theorem 1.12 of the book The Schur Complement and Its Applications, by Zhang, Fuzhen (Springer, 2005).

Comment: Or section A5.5 of the freely available book in pdf form, "Convex Optimization" by Boyd and Vandenberghe http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer. But I am still open to more direct proofs, if they exist.